# How to calculate quotients $R[[x,y]]/(f,g)$ with non-irreducible polynomials $f,g$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, intersection-theory

I want to calculate some intersection products for training my algebra knowledge, but I get stuck with the following example:
Take the circle $f=x^2+y^2-1$ and the line $g=y$ on the affine plane $X=\mathbb{A}^2$, I want to calculate the intersection index in the point $(1,0)$. That's where the quotient comes into play. The intersection index in a point $p$ is defined as

$$
\operatorname{mult}(p)=\dim\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/(f,g)
$$
with $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ the local ring at $p$. In our case we have
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2,(a,b)}=\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{(x-a,y-b)}\simeq \mathbb{C}[[x,y]],
$$
so in the end, we have
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2,(1,0)}/(x^2+y^2-1,y)=\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/((x+1)^2+y^2-1,y) \\
=\mathbb{C}[[x]]/((x+1)^2-1)=\mathbb{C}[[x]](x(x+2))\simeq\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}
$$
so the multiplicity would be $2$, as the dimension of $\mathbb{C}^2$ is $2$, which is clearly wrong as it should be $1$ for the point $(1,0)$ and $1$ for the point $(-1,0)$. Can you help me spot my mistake in the above calculation?

Furthermore if I use a point that is not in the intersection of the zero sets of $f$ and $g$, e.g. $p=(0,0)$, the result is analogously
$$
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^2,(0,0)}/(x^2+y^2-1,y)=\mathbb{C}[[x]]/((x-1)(x+1))\simeq \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}
$$
which cannot be correct as the dimension should be $0$ as there is no intersection.

I really appreciate any help solving my dilemma!

Comment: Isn’t $x+2$ invertible in the power series ring $\mathbb C[[x]]$? Similarly for both $x\pm1$. (They all have nonzero constant term.)

Comment: Oh yeah you're right! Everything with a non-zero constant term has an inverse in the power series ring, right?

Comment: That means that as these elements are invertible, the quotient just gives a point. That's why we get one dimension for the points $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ as we then have $x$ alone in the denominator which isn't invertible and thus yields $\mathbb{C}$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and for the point $(0,0)$ you are quotienting by a unit, so you get the zero ring.

Comment: Right, thanks that really helped a lot!